# How to add dates?

Tags: php, date

let's suppose I had a date in the format "YmdHis"

Normally, to add some time to a date I do the following

```
$date = date('YmdHis', strtotime("+ 2 days"));
```

and it would return a date in YmdHis format which is after two days

Now what if I wanted to add 2 days to specific date other than the current date? Considering that date is also in YmdHis format

Is that possible?

Comment: What format do you have the date in?  Unix timestamp?

Comment: Use the manual... [`strtotime("+2 days", $now)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: @Mr.Llama Why does that matter...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$day = '2010-01-23';
$NewDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . " +7 days"));
echo $NewDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects, there's already a [DateTime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method that does exactly what you're looking for.